# multiple DatagridView Rendering Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm able to add multiple datagridview 1 after another on panel.

by adding code of  SysDragon from the same forum

```
    Dim AllDataGrids As List(Of My_custom_DGV)
    Dim lastCtrl As Control
    AllDataGrids = New List(Of My_custom_DGV)

    For j As Int32 = 0 To 3

        Dim aDataGridView As New My_custom_DGV()
        aDataGridView.for_date = ""
        aDataGridView._count = week_count

        aDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        aDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Right
        aDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Left
        aDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom


        AllDataGrids.Add(aDataGridView)


    Next j

    For i As Integer = 1 To 3
        Dim dgv As My_custom_DGV = AllDataGrids(i)
        ' Dim dgv As DataGridView = AllDataGrids(i)

        If dataGrid_Panel.Controls.Count.Equals(0) Then
            dgv.Top = DataGridView1.Height + 20
        Else
            lastCtrl = dataGrid_Panel.Controls(dataGrid_Panel.Controls.Count - 1)
            dgv.Top = lastCtrl.Top + lastCtrl.Height + 5

        End If

        dataGrid_Panel.Controls.Add(dgv)

    Next
```

the problem is that when i scroll in between them then it is looking very bad(i.e. as i scroll,it is repeating the the image on panel again and again). does it render the view again when i Scroll,and may be calling the paint method of datagridview repeatedly. if yes then what is the solution?
Thanks.